# What do professional web developers use to generate sites?

Tags: web

Just wondering what pro web developers use to publish their sites. Also I would like to know what big sites have used, such as Amazon, Walmart, etc.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: There are *many* tools available for building websites and various online applications.  "Pro web developers" is an *extremely* broad category and covers more people and tools and technologies than any one person is going to be able to name.  Just pick some technologies and start with some tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

It's a difficult question to answer, I guess. The tools used by a developer depends on the customer requirements. It may be one of the following:

1. Static site with graphics and/or flash (simple business site)
2. Dynamic site with front-end html/CSS and database driven backend using php, perl, .net, Java, etc.
3. A large site that may use ecom along with content management system (CMS). There you may need CMS (such as Joomla) along with compatible plug-ins and customization.
4. For very popular sites such as Amazon, speed and bandwidth are very critical. Usually, though they start small (say, using PHP/MySQL, or ready-made CMS), they change according to their own requirements sooner or later using custom coding (Java is very popular). This is only my guess!

For co-ordination and publishing, GIT is very popular.

hope this helps.